# No puedo registrar un input pero que la primera letra no sea un número (Python)

Tags: python

Quiero que el usuario tenga un mínimo de 8 caracteres pero que no empiece la primera letra por un número y no se comprobarlo de esta manera.

```
usuarios = []
    a=1 
       while a==True:
            print("El nombre de usuario debe tener un maximo de 8 carácteres y que no comience por numero")
            usuario=(input("Nombre del primer usuario"))
            if len(usuario) <= 8 and usuario[0:1] != int:
                usuarios.append(usuario)
                a = 0
            else:
                print("Escribe un nombre que siga las especificaciones")
    print(usuarios)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para ver si una cadena (o caracter) es numérico, puedes usar el método `isnumeric`, con lo que la comparación queda así:

```
 if len(usuario) <= 8 and not usuario[0].isnumeric():
```

La otra observación es eliminar el uso de la variable `a` para controlar el ciclo. En su lugar, usa un `while True` y `break`, asi:

```
usuarios = []
while True:
    print("El nombre de usuario debe tener un maximo de 8 carácteres y que no comience por numero")
    usuario = (input("Nombre del primer usuario"))
    if len(usuario) <= 8 and not usuario[0].isnumeric():
        usuarios.append(usuario)
        break
    else:
        print("Escribe un nombre que siga las especificaciones")
print(usuarios)
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, ha sido muy util para mi

Comment: Hola @PatrickVerso69 Si te ha servido la respuesta de Candid Moe, la mejor forma de dar las gracias en StackOverflow es aceptando la respuesta en el tick  "aceptar respuesta",  y ¿Por qué no? ¡Darle también un voto positivo! Esto no solo le recomenpensara a  por la ayuda, si no que hará que la pregunta perdure en el tiempo y le pueda ser de ayuda a personas con el mismo problema que tú en el futuro! Te recomiendo leer [Vota pronto, vota con frecuencia](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2209/vota-pronto-vota-con-frecuencia)